# Node.js getting array from JS front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have array with objects which I want to store (or to database or to create a json file). I have this array in the js file (I fetch the data from api. I fetch it in the front-end and not in the back-end) . 
I want to know if there is any way to pass this array to the back end so i will be able to store it.

probably some people will suggest to fetch the data from the api in the back end, but i really need to leave it in the front end :/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So how about using localStorage instead

Comment: So you want to store the array in the front-end or in the back-end? You say "pass this array to the back end" and also "but i really need to leave it in the front end". I'm confused...

Comment: the size is too big, first it was in local storage. but im getting error because its full. i cannot clear the local storage, i need this data stored. thats why im trying to find a solution..

Comment: You can probably do it with an AJAX request, but without more information it is hard to tell

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from passing the array to the backend? That i dont know how to do it hehe.. how to pass this array from front end to back end.  --You can probably do it with an AJAX request, but without more information it is hard to tell ... i saw one solution with this method. i thought maybe there is more simple way to do so.. maybe even to put the array in hidden text area and get it with req.body.textarea or something like this...

Comment: @elnatanvazana You can do that with a ajax post request or a file. Store that array you fetched using the frontend in a file and then read that file from the backend.

Comment: do you mean to do AJAX post request and data : the array. and then in the backend to do get request and get this data? can you post an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this in the backend:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
    // Save the data available in req.body somewhere
    res.status(200).send('Got data');
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at 
http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Post your data to this endpoint from the frontend using something like axios, jquery or vanilla ajax. You may need to use an express middleware like bodyparser and configure it with the type of data you are posting from the frontend (json, urlencoded). You will find several detailed guides online.

Comment: Maybe im doing something wrong but im getting underfind when i console log req.body i did in the fron end ajax({type:'POST', url:'/data', data: array}) and i did in the backend the same what you posted and i did console.log(req.body) im getting undefined

Comment: @elnatanvazana Send that array in a json format. `data: {"array" : array}`. Then in the backend use bodyparser : `app.use(bodyparser.json())` before the app.post. You will need to install and require body-parser.

Comment: im doing json stringify in the front end, in the back end im doing json parse..i changed ajax to fetch and its working, thank you for your help

Comment: Happy to help. I'd say try finding tutorials/videos online before posting on stackoverflow. You will get downvoted for asking basic question without research. One reason why I am not very active on the site unless I have an unsolvable problem.

Comment: I was looking for answer before i asked, i was looking for second opinion, maybe some one has good idea how to solve my problem maybe differently.. anyway i dont mind to get down vote, i put my ego aside when i use the interner ;). anyway you are a good man and you helped me. god bless you